# Select option sort in php

Tags: php, sorting

I really need your help.

I´m using this code to write into text file from form:

```
$data = $_POST['jmeno'] . "\t" . $_POST['prijmeni'] . "\t" . $_POST['ulice'] . "\t" . $_POST['cislo_popisne'] . "\t" . $_POST['mesto'] . "\t" . $_POST['psc']. "\n";

$myfile = fopen("zakaznici.txt", "ab") or die("Unable to open file!");

fwrite($myfile, $data);

fclose($myfile);
```

This is my code to read from text file:

```
 $filename = 'zakaznici.txt';
$handle = fopen($filename, 'r');

$datain = fread($handle, filesize($filename));

$array = explode("\t",$datain);

echo "<table class='styl'><th>Jméno</th><th>Příjmení</th><th>Ulice</th><th>Číslo popisné</th><th>Město</th><th>PSČ</th><tr>".implode("</tr><tr>",array_map(function($a) {return "<td>".implode("</td><td>",explode("\t",trim($a)))."</td>";},explode("\n",$datain)))."</tr></table>";
```

And in table it looks like this:
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRpcm.jpg)

Any advice how to sort it alphabetically? I mean for example, when I choose "Jmeno" in select option a hit "Odeslat", I will get sorted table by column "Jmeno" like this (ivana, stepan, tomas).

Answer (score 1):

When using the explode function, it puts all the values in an array. What you can do before echoing the data, is sorting the array.

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

```
$data = "atest\tctest\tptest\tqtest\tbtest\tltest";

$values = explode("\t", $data);
sort($values, SORT_STRING);

echo "<table class='styl'><th>Jméno</th><th>Příjmení</th><th>Ulice</th><th>Číslo popisné</th><th>Město</th><th>PSČ</th>";
echo "<tr>";
foreach($values as $value)
{
    echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>";
}
echo "</tr></table>";
```

Result:

```
Jméno   Příjmení    Ulice   Číslo popisné   Město   PSČ
atest   btest   ctest   ltest   ptest   qtest
```

Answer (score 1):

I´m getting this.

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5hEW.jpg)

Really don´t know how to do it.